# Create type which requires only the specified fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Assume I have a type

```
type A = {
  a: string
  b?: number
  c: boolean
  d?: string
}
```

How could I derive a type from it where I only require `a` and `b` and leave everything else optional

```
type A2 = {
  a: string
  b: number
  c?: boolean
  d?: string
}
```

My approach was:

```
export type WithRequiredOnly<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P] } & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]+?: T[P] }

A2 = WithRequiredOnly<A, 'a'|'b'>
```

But this seems to still require the other fields...

Comment: What is your intent with `T &` in the definition at the beginning?  That seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type WithRequiredOnly<T, K extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Omit<T, K>>
```